# Meaning of “ $\Bbb{C} -(- \infty , 0]$”

Tags: complex-analysis

If I read in a book that, for example, we need to prove that $^3\sqrt{z}$ has exactly three determinations on $\Bbb{C} -(- \infty , 0]$ what is the meaning of “$\Bbb{C} -(- \infty , 0]$” ?

Thanks

Comment: It is the set of complex numbers that are not nonpositive real numbers. It is more common to see $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$, but the notation you stated is also usual

Comment: @Didier So basically $\Bbb{C} -(- \infty , 0]$ means all the complex mumbers with positive real part?

Comment: No. It means all complex numbers that are not in $(-\infty,0]$. For instance, $-1+i$ is such a complex number.

Comment: Cut with scissors directly across the real axis, starting at the origin and going all the way left.

Comment: @Didier Ok, so you only remove negative pure reals?

Comment: @UDAC Yes, but rather "nonpositive" than "negative"

Comment: ... so long as you understand "negative" to include $0$ as well, i.e. not in the "strict" sense.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, I forgot the 0. So basically, in the exercise, I have to found that ${z}^{1/3}$ has exactly three values different from -a, -b and -c , (a,b,c) positive reals including 0.

Comment: @UDAC I'm not confident in affirming much further, because I don't really understand the question (and I don't know what $a, b, c$ refer to). The set $\Bbb{C} - [0, \infty)$ is undoubtedly just as we've described, but I'm not 100% sure what it means for $\sqrt[3]{z}$ to have three "determinations" on this set. My best guess is that it's asking you to show that every complex number $z \in \Bbb{C} - [0, \infty)$ has exactly $3$ roots, which is true. However, it's more generally true for $\Bbb{C} - \{0\}$, so I'm not confident that I'm interpreting the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

"Every point of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ **except** the interval $(- \infty, 0]$". That is if "determination" as you write it (I guess you translated it from somewhere) is on open $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ with $f$ continuous function such that
\begin{align}
\forall w \in \Omega \text{ }\exp(f(w))=w.
\end{align}